# Height equal to dynamic width (CSS fluid layout) + Expand to contain overflow

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

Hi — is it possible to have a div with it's height equal to a fluid width expand to contain its content within a narrow viewport?

I figured out a work around with a solid colour div: http://jsfiddle.net/2nprw0xq/

But not with a border: http://jsfiddle.net/534k9e2n/

Here's the code I'm using. Thanks, B.

```
<div class="holder">
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape_outer">
<div class="shape_inner"> Text... </div>
</div>
</div>
```

.

```
.holder {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
.shape {
    margin-top: 100%;
}
.shape_outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid #111;
}
.shape_inner {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move border to your inner element and then add 100% width and 100% min-height, like this:

```
.shape_inner {
    border: 1px solid #111;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/534k9e2n/1/

Comment: Is there a way I can avoid overlapping of content below..? — @caeth http://jsfiddle.net/534k9e2n/4/

Comment: @boyce if you put them in the same container it will work, otherwise i don't know :) http://jsfiddle.net/534k9e2n/5/